# TapGesture inside collectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uigesturerecognizer

I want to add a doubleTap gesture or some other feature to a collection view that will download a file attached to the cell that is selected.

I have a double tap gesture recogniser working and when you double tap inside the collection view it will print the point.  However as soon as i try double tap on a cell the inbuilt gesture recogniser takes effect and didSelectItemAt is run.

Is there a way to add a double tap without triggering the code in didSelectItemAt?? Or any ideas for another method to achieve this functionality without adding a button to the viewController?

This is the gesture code i am playing with in viewDidLoad of the viewcontroller that has the collection view:

```
let doubleTap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didDoubleTap))
    doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    self.collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTap)
```

And my doubleTap function:

```
func didDoubleTap(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    let point: CGPoint = gesture.location(in: self.collectionView)

    print(point)

    if let selectedIndexPath: IndexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: point) {
        let selectedCell: UICollectionViewCell = self.collectionView.cellForItem(at: selectedIndexPath as IndexPath)!
        print("cell \(selectedCell) was double tapped")
    }
}
```

As a note, i have tried adding this to the cell itself but i couldn't get it working.  The cell is a custom UICollectionViewCell and there is no viewDidLoad function, so to create the gesture i would have to create a delegate that calls the code to set up the gesture from the viewController that holds the collection view and i was just getting errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `delaysTouchesBegan = true` on the gesture recognizer. This should delay the touch processing that leads to `didSelect` and run your action from the gesture recognizer

Comment: Thank you, nice simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the tap gesture recognizer to every cell in `cellForRowAtIndexpath` datasource method.